# Getting started with Zimbra API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, zimbra

I am wondering how I can go about using the Zimbra API.   I have looked everywhere for an API, and I have found no good references/tutorials about it.

I have a web application that I have developed in Ruby on Rails that I would like to communicate to Zimbra in order to fetch the calendar items to put in my own Calendar interface from within my application.

Can I do this ? and where can I start ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are some doc :

[SOAP API](http://zimbra.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/zimbra/trunk/ZimbraServer/docs/soap.txt?revision=843&view=markup)

[SOAP Admin API](http://zimbra.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/zimbra/trunk/ZimbraServer/docs/soap-admin.txt?view=markup)

you can also download zimbra and look at ZimbraServer/docs/soap.txt

Comment: note that the copy on sourceforge seems to be rather out of date ... a current version is to be found in you zimbra installation unter /opt/zimbra/docs

Answer (score 4):

Zimbra provide the soap api to get the calender and you can sent that calender data to you application using the XmlRpc Request.

Comment: but kapilbhai xmlRpc su 6 ? and Nilesh stack nu id apo ne ?

Comment: @AshokD : XML-RPC is a remote procedure call (RPC) protocol which uses XML to encode its calls and HTTP as a transport mechanism.

Comment: @AshokD : I do not have Nilesh stack id .

Comment: wah kapilbhai...vadhi gya ne ...:)

Answer (score 0):

There is a java version [here](http://blog.jeshurun.ca/technology/a-java-compliant-wsdl-for-zimbras-admin-soap-api) which also has a WSDL file for Zimbra's admin api. You may be able to use this to generate a client for ROR.